# VBA Run Time Error 13: Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, type-mismatch

My macro is a very simple replace program which identifies shortened parts of overall statements and replaces them with the full statement. For some reason I keep getting VBA error 13: Type Mismatch. The debugger identifies this error on the first of my replacement statements, then does not identify an error in the next two lines, when the program runs these lines even produce the expected result (I tested by commenting out specific lines). The debugger then finds an error in the rest of the statements after those two lines. I have no idea what is happening and would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

```
//

//

Sub Replacement()

    **'Define variables**

    Dim firstViolation As String

    Dim secondViolation As String

    Dim thirdViolation As String

    Dim fourthViolation As String

    Dim fifthViolation As String

    Dim sixthViolation As String

    Dim seventhViolation As String

    Dim eighthViolation As String

    Dim ninthViolation As String

    Dim tenthViolation As String

    Dim eleventhViolation As String

    Dim twelfthViolation As String

    Dim thirteenthViolation As String

    Dim fourteenthViolation As String


    **'Give variables values**

    These statements are incredibly long but I am confident there is no error as I simply set the pre-defined variables


    **'Code to replace the word violation with the correct descriptions**

    Range("G2:G100").Replace What:="IPMC-301.4 Emergency Phone Contact", Replacement:=firstViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("H2:H100").Replace What:="IPMC-302.3 Sidewalks", Replacement:=secondViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("I2:I100").Replace What:="IPMC-302.7 Accessory Structures", Replacement:=thirdViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("J2:J100").Replace What:="IPMC-302.8 Motor vehicles, boats and trailers", Replacement:=fourthViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("K2:K100").Replace What:="IPMC-302.10 Graffiti Removal", Replacement:=fifthViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("L2:L100").Replace What:="IPMC-302.13 Parking of motor vehicles",
    Replacement:=sixthViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("M2:M100").Replace What:="IPMC-304.2 Protective Treatment", Replacement:=seventhViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("N2:N100").Replace What:="IPMC-304.3 [F] Premises Identification", Replacement:=eighthViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("O2:O100").Replace What:="IPMC-304.6 Exterior Walls", Replacement:=ninthViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("P2:P100").Replace What:="IPMC-304.7 Roofs and Drainage", Replacement:=tenthViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("Q2:Q100").Replace What:="IPMC-304.3.1 Alley Frontage Identification", Replacement:=eleventhViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("R2:R100").Replace What:="IPMC-307.1  Accumulation of rubbish or garbage", Replacement:=twelfthViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("S2:S100").Replace What:="IPMC-307.2.3 Container Locks", Replacement:=thirteenthViolation, LookAt:=xlPart

    Range("T2:T100").Replace What:="IPMC-307.3.4 Additional Capacity Requirements", Replacement:=fourteenthViolation, LookAt:=xlPart
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see the replacement values for one that succeeds and one that fails. It runs for me without anything to replace and unitialized strings. As a side note, please use the VBA comment character - a single-quote - for your comments. I makes it easier to copy and test in the VBE.

Comment: Can you paste the section section where you assign values?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is long and it's hard to identify issues there without having the full code.
First of all I'd try to siplify your code. Take a look at below and see if it helps. Arrays are used. If you are not familiar with them, look them up in google.

```
Sub replace_strings()

Dim ArrayCh() As Variant
Dim ArrayChTo() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

 ArrayCh = Array("IPMC-301.4 Emergency Phone Contact", "IPMC-302.3 Sidewalks") ' strings to change
 ArrayChTo = Array("blah", "blah blah") ' strings to change to


For i = LBound(ArrayCh) To UBound(ArrayCh)
    With ActiveSheet.Column(7 + i) 'G column where you start from in you code
                                    '+i - given in Arrays the frist index is 0
                                    'then it will add 1,2,3... as we loop the array
        .Replace What:=ArrayCh(i), _
        Replacement:=ArrayChTo(i), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        MatchCase:=True
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```